# Python equivalent function to cvCalcEigenObjects

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, face-recognition

I'm trying 'translate' the sample code in [here](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/page_4.html), but i can't find equivalent python function to `cvCalcEigenObjects` written in c language from `cvaux.h`.

Comment: If you need to, you can use the `ctypes` foreign function interface to invoke functions in a C shared library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to use the functions of numpy library for linear algebra.